# Is it possible to create an "empty" object from a TypeScript interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, interface, typescript-typings

Suppose you have a very large object defined as a TypeScript interface:

```
interface AccountInterface {
  accountIdentifier?: string;
  sid?: string;
  idToken?: {
    aio?: string;
  };
  idTokenClaims?: {
      aio?: string;
  };
}
```

I would like the object to always have its properties and sub properties. They can either be a string or an empty string:

```
let account = {
  accountIdentifier: "",
  sid: "",
  idToken: {
    aio: "",
  },
  idTokenClaims: {
    aio: "",
  },
};
```

Reading the other questions I thought it would have been possible to do this:

```
const emptyAccount = {} as AccountInterface

console.log('emptyAccount ', emptyAccount)
console.log('emptyAccount.sid ', emptyAccount.sid)
```

But this doesn't create an object with all the properties as empty strings as desired.

It would be great if something like this would be possible, so there's no need to duplicate the object in the code, as in one for the interface and one for the object with empty string properties.

Comment: I don't think there's a "default value that matches interface" feature in typescript and I also don't see any sensible way of providing one automatically. Why would an empty string be default? If the type is `string|number|null` then what would be the default. If the value is optional (which in your case they all are) is the default `undefined` or the default of the type if it would exist and if so why is it optional then?

Comment: "*Reading the other questions*" - which ones? Please link them.

Comment: I'm new to TS so still learning here. Updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [`class` that implements that `interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#implementing-an-interface), adding the default values, and use that to create your objects. You are still re-writing the same structure elsewhere, but now you only have to do it one time, and you could use the `constructor` to initialize your object with different values if you want.

```
interface AccountInterface {
  accountIdentifier?: string;
  sid?: string;
  idToken?: {
      aio?: string;
  };
  idTokenClaims?: {
      aio?: string;
  };
}

class Account implements AccountInterface {
  accountIdentifier = '';
  sid = '';
  idToken = { aio: '' };
  idTokenClaims = { aio: '' };
}

const emptyAccount = new Account();
```

Also, as pointed out by @apokryfos, you can also use the class to type objects, so there's no need to define both an `instance` and a `class` unless you are going to have objects implementing that instance that haven't been created using the class (as those would not have the methods defined in the class).

If you want to avoid using `class` and use a `function` to do something similar, you totally can:

```
function createAccount(): AccountInterface {
  return {
    accountIdentifier = '';
    sid = '';
    idToken = { aio: '' };
    idTokenClaims = { aio: '' };
  };
}

const emptyAccount = createAccount();
```

Comment: You don't even need to have the interface at all. You can declare the types in the class and then TypeScript is very happy to use the class both as a type and as a value depending on context

Comment: Can it be done without a `class`? I'd like to use functions ir possible.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'm just assuming the interface is going to be there anyway for some reason. Maybe you might have objects with those properties that are not instances of the class.

Comment: The goal was actually to avoid having to type out 2 times the object properties. That's why I wanted to instantiate the object from the interface without typing it all out again.

Comment: @apokryfos how is that done with a function? That would be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @DarkLite1 You can do something similar without a class, but you would still have to type everything one more time in the `createAccount` function you define for that. Check the updated example.

Comment: Check! Thank you :) I just thought this would've been possible without retyping the property names. Closing this one then, thanks again to all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`const emptyAccount = {} as AccountInterface` should create an object. But your AccountInterface only includes properties which may exist but must not (because of the ?). So an empty object completely matches your AccountInterface.

If you want to have a property with a default value to be included then you will have to declare it in your interface.

```
interface AccountInterface {
    accountIdentifier: string|null // <- will be included in {} as AccountInterface
    sid?: string // <- will not be included in {} as AccountInterface
}
```

Comment: the `emptyAccount` object is still not having the property `accountIdentifier`, even when taking away all the question marks.